# Why does the count property of get_the_tags always return 0?

Tags: tags

I am trying to build a custom tag cloud widget. If I view post #1 which has tags of `foo,bar,code` it says the counts for all those tags are 0, even if post #2 uses the exact same tags. I have a frontend form that modifies the post's tags with the following:

```
wp_set_post_tags($this->id, $_POST['tags']);
```

Then, when I view the post, i get the tags with

```
$tags = get_the_tags(get_the_ID());
if(count($tags) > 0){
    foreach($tags as $tag){
       echo $tag->name."(".$tag->count.")";
    }
}
```

In the above code, $tag->name returns the correct tags for each post, but $tag->count is always 0. Does wp_set_post_tags maybe not update the counts in the wp_term_taxonomy data table? Should I use something other than wp_set_post_tags or something other than get_the_tags?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$tags = get_the_tags(get_the_ID());
if(count($tags) > 1){
    foreach($tags as $tag){
       echo $tag->name."(".$tag->count.")";
    }
}
```

The get_the_tags_ function returns an array buts indexes do not begin at 0 as they are term ID's

Comment: Sorry, i meant $tag->count always returns 0, not count($tags)